# Frozen Synapse online play customization?

Tags: frozen-synapse

There seems to be a huge discrepancy between offline AI Skirmish options and what can be arranged online.

When customizing an online challenge, can you:

- adjust the map size?
- adjust the turn limit?
- adjust the turn time (5s, 10s, etc.)?
- if no, has the developer addressed why?

I would like to play larger, longer battles with my friends. I know you can add/remove soldiers, but it gets silly after a certain point when you're stuck on these tiny maps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirmed this myself.

You can:

- alter turn total
- alter turn length (seconds)

You cannot:

- alter map size (lame!)

I got on IRC and asked a dev why I can't alter map size, and his answer was "because", so there you go.

Answer (score 0):

I saw some of these options under advanced games but the screen was so intimidating I didn't spend much time there.  I imagine you will find what you are looking for there.

Comment: I think you're getting the offline advanced and online advanced confused. They're quite different.

Comment: This was when I challenged a friend; perhaps it only works with friends and not with random opponents.